# Submitting to Call for Submissions After Deadline

Tags: journals, paper-submission, editors, special-issue

I have an unpublished manuscript. A journal I would have liked to submit the manuscript to as a regular submission has a call for submissions for a special issue of the journal on XYZ with a target publication date of next year. My manuscript would be a near perfect fit for that special issue. The problem is that the deadline passed three months ago.

In this scenario, is it fair to email the editor to ask if it is possible to submit your paper first for the special issue, for which it would be a good fit, but several months past the posted deadline?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a week after the deadline you can probably still make it. Three months - probably not. They'd be pretty deep into the review process already, and your paper would hold up the special issue.

Still, no harm asking. It's possible they lack papers and will be happy to consider yours.